# PHP Parse error... syntax error unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

Tags: php

I can't figure out where this error is located. Line 1 is `<?php` also i'm using a phpIDE app and its not showing any errors / missing braces.

PHP Parse error:  **syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /home/ratemy/public_html/kernel/parser.php(190) : eval()'d code on line 1**

code lines from 167 - 200... line 190 is marked below.

```
# Format replaced vars
    function do_format($value,$s) {
            global $en;
            $value = (isset($en[$value]) ? $en[$value] : @constant($value));
            $i = strtolower($s);
            if (strpos($i,'echo') || strpos($i,'define')) {
                    $value = str_replace('"','`',$value);
                    $value = str_replace(chr(39),'`',$value);
                    }
            return $value;
            }

# Execute template block
    function exec_block($start, $end, $jump = -2) {
            $this->tpi = $start - 1;
            while ($this->tpi < $end) {
                    $s = $this->templ_read();
                    $this->s = $this->template_replace_vars($s);
                    if ($this->act[$this->tpi] == 'continue_loop') return false;
                    if ($this->act[$this->tpi] == 'break_loop') {
                            $this->cancel_loop = true;
                            return false;
                            }
                    eval('$this->'.$this->act[$this->tpi].'();'); // LINE 190
                    }
            if ($jump != -2)
                    $this->tpi = $jump;
            }

# Echo a line
    function do_print() {
            echo $this->s;
            }
```

... snippet

there is more too the file is there a way I can figure out where this error is actually at?

Comment: It's in line 190, which obviously contains a call to `eval()`

Comment: can you post any of the code from `/home/ratemy/public_html/kernel/parser.php`?

Comment: @knittl i've edited the question to show line 190

Comment: @jere see changes above, thanks.

Comment: did you try removing those `()` in `eval('$this->'.$this->act[$this->tpi].'();');`? the error says there's an unexpected parentheses

Comment: @jere so the line would become `eval('$this->'.$this->act[$this->tpi]);` right?

Comment: without the () the page doesn't load at all

Comment: @acctman, can you do `echo $this->act[$this->tpi];` right before the call to the `eval()` and post the output? (of the echo command)

Comment: @jere multiple entries `do_print if_start do_eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a function the name of which is given by `$this->act[$this->tpi]`, use this:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $this->act[$this->tpi]));
```

Don't do `eval`, it is evil.

Answer (score 1):

@knittl wrote :  It's in line 190, which obviously contains a call to eval()"  1 min ago

@knittl is correct - The error is on that line in your file. `eval()'d code on line 1` means that the error is on the first line of the code that is being eval()'d on line 190 of file parser.php.

Put this on the line before line 190:

```
echo '$this->'.$this->act[$this->tpi].'();';
```

And it will show you the code that is being eval'ed that is causing the error.

Comment: I've edited my question to include line 190

Comment: The answers still the same - the error is in the code being eval'ed. Not in the code that is calling the eval.